# Accesing XHR Request Info From Page In Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So I have a page, I can open the Console and go to the Network tab, I see this

[image]

So I was wondering, could I use Javascript to read the info from those XHR messages? I don't know if this is possible or a stupid question because I'm pretty new to networking.

Comment: Chances are you're only seeing this *because* some JavaScript fired the XHR to read the response messages.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)?

Comment: Is this a page you control the code in? Not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I don't think so, it seems like that is for timing things locally on the webpage, not reading the contents of XHR messages.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking for. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Yes, JavaScript can do lots of things when running in the right environment (hint: the whole console is written in JS), but your question is much too generic.

Comment: Ok so I'm gonna try this again, since no one seems to understand. Basically if you click on one of those white things with numbers on them (Requests?) you get their contents, like this: http://imgur.com/a/xamjF. How can I use Javascript to get that same requests contents?

Comment: I think you might be looking for the [`responseText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) property then, but I'm still not sure. You should probably use a tutorial on making AJAX requests.

Comment: You can download the request as a `.har` file at `DevTools`. You can also use `ServiceWorker` if you are serving the response. Else, you can simply request the URL  and read the response. If you are only interested in the occurrence of and metadata of requests you can utilize `PerformanceObserver`.